# Control a perl script's CPU utilization?

Tags: perl, cpu-usage

I am doing a lot of file searching based on a criteria in multiple iterations from my Perl script and it seems to take up 100% of the CPU time. Is there a way to control my script CPU utilization? I read somewhere about putting empty sleep cycles in my script. But I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: This is platform dependent. What OS are you running on?

Comment: @bish  If there are no other processes needing the CPU why should he let it, waste good cycles when they can be put to good use ??

Comment: I am running my scripts on Windows. Yes there are other processes that are also running. I was to be less obtrusive with my scripts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could lower the process (Perl's) priority, as assigned by the OS:  [windows](http://www.itworld.com/nls_windows_lowpriority060814) or  [linux](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/unice.htm)

example for lowest priority:

*windows*

```
start /LOW  perl <myscript>
```

*linux*

```
nice +19 perl <myscript>
```

Comment: This looks like the simplest solution. I'll try this before the others and report back.

Comment: This is an easy solution but requires the users knowledge or that you create a startup script or an alias. If however, you use setpriority()  the code will always renice/change priority as intended. The type of application and use should decide what solution to choose.

Answer (score 7):

A great way to improve CPU utilization is to use better algorithms. Don't guess where your code is spending all its time: use a profiler. [`Devel::NYTProf`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-NYTProf/) is a fantastic tool for this.

Be sure to keep [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) in mind. For example, say part of your program uses a quadratic algorithm and with some effort you could replace it with a linear one. Hooray! But if the code in question accounts for only 5% of the total runtime, your most heroic effort can bring no better than a tiny five-percent improvement. Use a profiler to determine whether opportunities for greater speedup are available elsewhere.

You don't tell us what you're searching for, and even the best known algorithms can be CPU-intensive. Consider that your operating system's scheduler has been written, hand-tuned, tested, and rewritten to use system resources efficiently. Yes, some tasks require specialized schedulers, but such cases are rare—even less likely given that you're using Perl.

Don't take it as a bad sign that your code is eating up CPU. You may be surprised to learn that one of the hardest challenges in realtime systems, where performance is crucial, is to keep the CPU busy rather than idling.

Comment: My script spends a lot of time doing menial tasks, like searching text in files, running external programs, capturing and parsing their output, rather than any specialized algorithm. In general, I agree with your opinion. I am not particularly concerned that my script is eating up the CPU. But more with the fact that this CPU usage is affecting other programs and services running on the same Windows server. So that's it. A simple low process priority seems to serve my purpose at present. Yes, profiling is good in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on NYTProf! note to self: the only sort of a guide with steps I could find so far is [perlmonks: mod_perl application profiling - Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=833194).. Cheers!

Comment: The above only applies for synchronous, single-threaded processes. Anything that uses locks, coroutines, or synchronized resource access, will leave your profiling efforts in vain, if you don't use something like [coz](https://github.com/plasma-umass/coz) and a healthy bit of statistics.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [sleep or usleep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html). Another thing you can do is to lower the process priority.

Update:
See [setpriority()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_setpriority.htm)

Comment: Perl's `setpriority` function is just a wrapper around the system call with the same name. As such, it's a fatal error to call it on platforms that don't implement it (e.g. Windows).

Comment: I just confirmed this. `setpriority()` is not implemented in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Just sleep:

```
while ($not_done_yet) {
    do_stuff_here();
    sleep 1; # <-- sleep for 1 second.
}
```

or slightly more fancy, do N operations per sleep cycle:

```
my $op_count = 0;
while ($not_done_yet) {
    do_stuff_here();

    $op_count ++;
    if ($op_count >= 100) {
        $op_count = 0;
        sleep 1; # <-- sleep for 1 second every 100 loops.
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I get the idea. So I'll have to break up my tasks into groups that can be iterated.

Answer (score 2):

[sleep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html) + [time](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/time.html) + [times](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/times.html) can kinda do this.

```
my $base = time;
my $ratio = 0.5;
my $used = 0;
sub relax {
    my $now = time;
    my ($total) = times;
    return if $now - $base < 10 or $total - $used < 5;  # otherwise too imprecise
    my $over = ($total - $used) - $ratio * ($now - $base);
    $base = $now + ($over > 0 && sleep($over));
    $used = $total;
}
```

(Untested...)  Sprinkle enough `relax` calls throughout your code and this should average out to near or under 50% CPU time.

---

[BSD::Resource](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?BSD::Resource) can do this less invasively, and you might as well grab [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::HiRes) for higher precision.

```
my $base = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
my (undef, $hard) = getrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU);
my $interval = 10;
if ($hard != RLIM_INFINITY && $hard < $interval) {$interval = $hard / 2}
my $ratio = 0.5;
$SIG{XCPU} = sub {
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, $interval, $hard);
    my $now = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
    my $over = $interval - $ratio * ($now - $base);
    $base = $now + ($over > 0 && sleep($over));
};
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, $interval, RLIM_INFINITY);
```

(Also untested...)  On a system which supports it, this should ask the OS to signal you every `$interval` seconds of CPU time, at which point you reset the counter and sleep.  This should not require any changes to the rest of your code.

Comment: Has to be tested. But looks like an interesting solution to generally control CPU usage with numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Is your script actually doing things the whole time?  For example, if you calculate a mandelbrot set, you'll have loops that consume CPU, but are actively processing data all the time.

Or do you have loops where you are waiting for more data to process:

```
while(1) { 
    process_data() if data_ready();
}
```

In the first case, setting priority is probably the best solution.  It will slow computation, but only as much as needed to service any other processes on the system.

In the second case, you can improve CPU utilization drastically by sleeping for only a fraction of a second.

```
while(1) { 
    process_data() if data_ready();
    select( undef, undef, undef, 0.1 );
}
```

If you are pulling data from a source that `select` can operate on, so much the better.  The you can arrange for your loop to block until data is ready.

```
use IO::Select;
my $s = IO::Select->new($handle);

while(1) { 
    process_data() if $s->can_read;
}
```

Select works on sockets and file-handles on *NIX systems.  On Windows systems, you can only select against sockets.